# Socket.DuplicateAndClose with async/await fails with E_INVALIDARG

Tags: c#, sockets, async-await

I'm having trouble using Socket.DuplicateAndClose in tandem with C#'s async/await feature. I've isolated the problem to a minimal test case, shown below. Note that using `writer.WriteLine` instead of `WriteLineAsync` (and `Flush` instead of `FlushAsync`) makes the program succeed without errors. Introducing async/await, however, throws an exception on the `WriteLineAsync("Second socket")` line.

Apologies for the rather long minimal test case, it's as small as I could get it.

Is it a bug in .net? Or am I doing something wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SocketTest
{
    class Program
    {
        // Simple hosting socket, not actually part of the problem, just something to connect to in Main()
        static void HostSocket(object dummy)
        {
            var listen = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 12345);
            listen.Start();
            var client = listen.AcceptTcpClient();
            listen.Stop();
            var reader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
            while (true)
            {
                string line;
                try
                {
                    line = reader.ReadLine();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Server exception:");
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                    break;
                }
                if (line == null)
                    break;
                Console.WriteLine("Server: " + line);
            }
            reader.Dispose();
            Console.WriteLine("Server closed");
        }

        // The main problem
        static async Task RealMain()
        {
            // Connect to localhost and write a line to it. This works.
            var client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 12345);
            var writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
            await writer.WriteLineAsync("First socket");
            await writer.FlushAsync();
            // Duplicate the socket with Socket.DuplicateAndClose, passing the current PID
            var info = client.Client.DuplicateAndClose(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
            // Close() must be after Duplicate, otherwise ObjectDisposedException
            writer.Close();
            // Create a TcpClient using the SocketInformation struct obtained from DuplicateAndClose
            var second = new TcpClient();
            second.Client = new Socket(info);
            writer = new StreamWriter(second.GetStream());
            // Write the second line from the new socket
            await writer.WriteLineAsync("Second socket"); // EXCEPTION HERE
            await writer.FlushAsync();
            writer.Close();
        }

        // Boot the server and then start the client
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Thread(HostSocket) { IsBackground = true }.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            RealMain().Wait();
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

The exception is:

```
System.AggregateException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=One or more errors occurred.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
       at SocketTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\users\khyperia\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\SocketTest\Program.cs:line 69
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: 
       HResult=-2146232800
       Message=Unable to write data to the transport connection: The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG)).
       Source=System
       StackTrace:
            at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.BeginWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
            at System.IO.Stream.<BeginEndWriteAsync>b__16(Stream stream, ReadWriteParameters args, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
            at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncTrim[TInstance,TArgs](TInstance thisRef, TArgs args, Func`5 beginMethod, Func`3 endMethod)
            at System.IO.Stream.BeginEndWriteAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
            at System.IO.Stream.WriteAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            at System.IO.Stream.WriteAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
            at System.IO.StreamWriter.<FlushAsyncInternal>d__1e.MoveNext()
         --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
            at SocketTest.Program.<RealMain>d__1.MoveNext() in c:\users\khyperia\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\SocketTest\Program.cs:line 60
       InnerException: 
            HResult=-2147024809
            Message=The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
            Source=mscorlib
            StackTrace:
                 at System.Threading.ThreadPool.BindIOCompletionCallbackNative(IntPtr fileHandle)
                 at System.Threading.ThreadPool.BindHandle(SafeHandle osHandle)
                 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BindToCompletionPort()
                 at System.Net.Sockets.BaseOverlappedAsyncResult.SetUnmanagedStructures(Object objectsToPin)
                 at System.Net.Sockets.OverlappedAsyncResult.SetUnmanagedStructures(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketAddress socketAddress, Boolean pinSocketAddress)
                 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBeginSend(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags, OverlappedAsyncResult asyncResult)
                 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginSend(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags, SocketError& errorCode, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
                 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginSend(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
                 at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.BeginWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
            InnerException:
```

Comment: The question is totally valid by itself, but DuplicateAndClose is misused most of the time due to misunderstandings. Can you clarify why you thing DuplicateAndClose is the best solution for your requirements?

Comment: @usr, I'm writing an IRC bot for fun, and I'm using AppDomains to implement reloading of code for updates. Basically I chuck out the entire old codebase (which was running in an isolated AppDomain), spin up another AppDomain, and pass the socket from the old domain to the new one (to never disconnect from the server). As far as I know, sockets cannot be passed between AppDomains like that, and require a DuplicateAndClose. Granted I could use a "proxy" that persists the connection, and the clients connect to the proxy instead of the server, but DuplicateAndClose seems simpler.

Comment: Makes sense. I'd try making the parent/controller AppDomain handle the connections and only put the bot logic into the disposable AppDomain. In other words stream the data across AppDomains instead of passing the socket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.duplicateandclose%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> If the process creating the socket uses asynchronous methods (BeginReceive or BeginSend), the process must first set the UseOnlyOverlappedIO property to true; otherwise, the socket is bound to the completion port of the creating process, which may cause an ArgumentNullException to be thrown on the target process.

Though it is not the `ArgumentNullException` thrown, try this:

```
var info = client.Client.DuplicateAndClose(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
info.Options |= SocketInformationOptions.UseOnlyOverlappedIO;
```

Comment: Thanks, somehow missed that when looking through the documentation. Fixes both the test case as well as the larger application that I first had the problem in.